# Unable to connect to repository in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: packages, miktex, repositories

In MiKTeX 2.9 Package manager, when I'm trying to synchronize it writes me a message: "The remote package repository is not online...", but I'know server is online (I can use FTP to download packages manualy). When I'm trying to change repository it shows me empty list. Like that:
[image: Empy list]

What can I do to fix this without manual downloading packages from repo?

Comment: Wait. Imho the main server with the list of repositories is down, and normally there is a reason when Christian disables it. If you badly need a package you can download it from CTAN (along with miktex-zz-XXX-files which contains the database info) and use a local repository.

Comment: Christian wrote in the miktex mailing list " The server (repositories) is (are) currently unstable because some maintenance needs to be done. Everything should be in its right place next week. Enjoy the weekend..."

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems that the problem still persists

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. : No it was fine the last two weeks. But it seems down now.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: There is a message on the website that there is a problem: http://www.miktex.org/.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you help me a bit? I need to install the package caption. I've already download the package from CTAN, and put on the desktop the folder caption. Afterward, with Miktex, I try to load by local repository, but I get the error 'Not a local package repository'. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. get the caption package from here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages. Download also the two databases miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma and miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma. Put everything in a folder.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes the miktex maintainer disables the main server with the list of repositories e.g. when a serious bug has appeared to avoid that people download a broken package. Sometimes the main server is simply down.

In both cases the best is to wait and to check if there are messages on the miktex website or the miktex mailing list.

If you badly need a package you can download it from CTAN from the miktex package folder (http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/) along with the "package databases" (two miktex-zz-XXX-files). Put everything in some empty folder and use it as local repository.

Answer (score 3):

If [the miktex api is actually online](http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories) and displaying valid mirrors, the api might just be bugged. At the time of writing both the GetRepository4 and the VerifyRepository2 action in the api seem to be broken. However, the PickRepository4 action works fine, and since the api returns it, the application assumes it is a valid repository. You can verify if that is the case for you by opening a command console and running `mpm --pick-repository-url` in the appropriate directory. If it displays an url instead of an error this solution should work for you.

Instead of doing the following steps, you can simply uninstall miktex, and check the option that it should clean up after itself. It will delete all temporary files, and the register keys it uses. The downside is that after re-installing miktex, you'll need to install all packages again. Yaaaaaay... :(

**Editing the register might cause all kinds of problems, including all kinds of things crashing. Always make a backup before editing the register. If in doubt, go for the safe route and read the previous paragraph.**

---

To get your installation working again, open regedit.exe (e.g. via <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM\`. It should contain three keys, namely `RemoteRepository`, `RepositoryReleaseState` and `RepositoryType`. Delete these keys.

MiKTeX package manager (MPM) will now default to asking the api for the closest repository instead of using the one you previously defined, which will work in most cases.