# Package repositories not showing up when updating Miktex

Tags: miktex

I'm trying to update Miktex and when I select the option "Let me choose a remote package repository", no package repository is showing up.  Instead, I just see this:

[image]

Updating also fails when I choose the "Use the nearest package repository" option.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

(Does this just mean the main server with the list of repositories is down for maintenance or something?  I found this [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/unable-to-connect-to-repository-in-miktex-2-9).  Apologies if this question is off-topic because it's too localized in time.)

Edit: Ah, it's working now.  I guess it was just that a server was down or something.

Comment: I don't know if it was offline one hour ago, but currently it is working for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's working for me now too, thanks, I guess it was just offline earlier.

Comment: I was updating, got some errors, and the next thing I know nothing is working.  I wound up having to uninstall and reinstall both MikTeX and my editor (twice).  Not a fun day!

Comment: I have this right now (since last night). Further if i run on the command line `mpm --list-repositories`, output is `No package repositories are currently available.` (on several computers). I get repos are down...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to repository in MiKTeX 2.9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/unable-to-connect-to-repository-in-miktex-2-9)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a local server being down temporarily.