# MiKTeX empty remote repository list (connection problem?)

Tags: miktex, update

I installed the latest version of MiKTeX 64bit on windows 10. I am trying to change the remote repository without success. The wizard does not show any suggestion as shown in the capture below. I don't have any proxy in my network. What could be the problem?!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the servers for MiKTeX are down for maintanance.  If it tooks more time it is mentioned on the homepage, for small maintanance not.

Just try it in 6 hours or so again.

If that does not work please check Ulrikes answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/unable-to-connect-to-repository-in-miktex-2-9).