# MikTeX won't let me install packages

Tags: r, protext

I'm trying to learn how to use TeX within R. I've downloaded R, RStudio, and [proTeXt](http://www.tug.org/begin.html). When I try to compile it, I receive a message that I am missing several packages; however, when I try to find a repository (change repository > packages shall be installed from the internet) instead of pulling up the list of different internet repositories I get nothing--it gives me no repositories to choose from.

I have spent hours searching the internet, but I can't seem to find a way to install the packages.

I **did** see and follow the instructions of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/unable-to-connect-to-repository-in-miktex-2-9) but it I couldn't get my computer to find the downloads and recognize a folder as a repository.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you launch MiKTeX Package Manager?

Comment: It didn't recognize a repository to grab them from.

Comment: !!! There are more or less a hundred repositories all over the world. Did you click on ‘Change Repository’? And did you run is as Administrator?

Comment: Yes I clicked change repository.

Comment: In general you should choose "install missing packages on the demand" or similar.

Comment: I think the problem was I don't think I have administrator  privileges on the computer I'm currently using (a work computer). So I uninstalled MikTeX and when I reinstalled it using proTeXt I chose the install complete version option so all of the packages would download with the program itself. Now it seems to be working so far.

Comment: Yep, you need admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was I don't think I have administrator privileges on the computer I'm currently using (a work computer). So I uninstalled MikTeX and when I reinstalled it using proTeXt I chose the install complete version option so all of the packages would download with the program itself. Now it seems to be working so far.