# The remote package repository is not online. You have to choose another repository

Tags: miktex, updating

After updating MikTex last night I am getting the error message in subject when trying to install or update the packages.

By default I was using http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ but to try and recover from this error I switched the updater to use the "nearest" repository which happened to be http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages and that also threw the same error.

Then I changed the updater to "allow me to choose the package repository" but the list that comes next is empty.

Did the last night's update to MikTex break the repository listing/querying in general, or something is wrong with my installation?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I suspect miktex is all down again; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242
and
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300047/

Comment: Working now!...

Comment: @ajeh , how did you solve this problem?