# Texmaker not finding miktex packages?

Tags: miktex, texmaker

Complete LaTeX begginer here! I've installed MiKTeX and Texmaker but when I try to run the build I get these errors:

[image: Error]

I download the file using mpm package manager just to find out that other file in allPacks.tex not found. How to install all MiKTeX packages at once?

Comment: Welcome, do you have the basic installation of MikTeX or the full installation. The message can be expected with the minimal install.

Comment: To get a full MiKTeX install you need to use the MiKTeX Net Installer, with the basic installation of MiKTeX you can use the Package Manager to install extra packages.

Comment: You can open the package manager (admin), select all uninstalled package and let it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are unfortunate to have installed MiKTeX in a moment when their server is disabled. See Ulrike Fischer's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284940/114544.
You should be able to download packages as soon as the repositories are up again.