# Only one package repository available, seems to have caused problems

Tags: repositories, update

When I try to install packages or updates, this is the only repository available (see below). The Warning message says your MiKTeX version is outdated. When I tried to updated MiKTeX using this repository, I started having problems compiling tex files that used to work. This repository has been the only one available to me for about a week now -- on several machines in the same geographic location. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you synchronised the list of repositories?

Comment: Under the tab "Repository" in MiKTeX package manager, I select Synchronize and nothing changes. Is that what you mean by synchronising the list?

Comment: Maybe related: [Unable to connect to repository in MiKTeX 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/unable-to-connect-to-repository-in-miktex-2-9)

Comment: There has been a bug report about this https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2612/ but with not enough info to decide what could be the source of the problem (proxy, old binaries, virus, some local provider problems, ...). Did you try to use mpm on the command line https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/mpm.html?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer when I use mpm on the command line and list repositories, I still get only that same repository back

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy and I get the same problem on two different machines that likely don't have the same virus

Comment: The miktex package works fine for me, and there hasn't be a lot of questions about this problem. This means that it is a rather local problem and without more info it is probably impossible to solve it. You could try to create a trace (https://docs.miktex.org/faq/troubleshooting.html) or use some process monitor to get more clues about what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried through mpm by specifing your repo as in `mpm --update --repository=ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`

Comment: Be aware that some organization firewalls block FTP on their LAN. For example, I cannot obtain anything via FTP on the public access WiFi at my university. So, If I obtain something via FTP when I am elsewhere, then try to update it when I am at the university, it will fail, because it seeks the former FTP transfer. If possible, I must manually change to an HTTP or HTTPS connection.

Comment: this technical problem bound to a certain point in the time-space-continuum has likely been resolved since the time it was asked and I voted to close the question as "off topic" lest it gets bumped by the system again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with thymaro. (Not sure why the system does show this option to me..)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just now, and running the MikTeX Update utility several times (until no more updates are available) worked for me, letting MikTeX select the geographically closest repository.