# Miktex 2.9 trying to install dvips after update (win 7)

Tags: dvips, update, miktex2.9

after updating my miktex 2.9 distribution it is not compiling correctly my old files, but giving me the error

> Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Lebenslauf".tex
>
> Unfortunately, the package dvips could not be installed.Please check the log file: C:/Users/sirui/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
>
> Kommando abgestürzt: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Lebenslauf".tex
>
> Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

It seems to be trying to install the dvips packages which is no more available on ctan.

The log is as follows:

> 2017-10-30 14:54:42,877+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Lebenslauf.tex
> 2017-10-30 14:54:42,893+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
> 2017-10-30 14:54:42,893+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
> 2017-10-30 14:54:45,623+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package dvips triggered by fonts\enc\dvips\base\8r.enc
> 2017-10-30 14:54:48,004+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The remote package repository is outdated. You have to choose another repository.
> 2017-10-30 14:54:48,004+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: ="url="http://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/""
> 2017-10-30 14:54:48,004+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\RestRemoteService.cpp
> 2017-10-30 14:54:48,004+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 275
> 2017-10-30 14:54:48,144+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1

Has someone experienced this too and what would be the best solution to this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is currently a problem with the server see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/27. If you need the packages you will have to get them from ctan and install through a local repository (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/unable-to-connect-to-repository-in-miktex-2-9/284940#284940)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ulrike Fischer, the answer to the issue was a server problem that day which caused the package to not be retrievable. It works fine now. See the original answer below.

> There is currently a problem with the server see github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/27. If you need the packages you will have to get them from ctan and install through a local repository (tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251242/…) – Ulrike Fischer 21 hours ago